# Is ConsistentRead param of DynamoDb scan really supported in JS AWS SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When I invoke scan with ConsistentRead param I receive

> "Unexpected key 'ConsistentRead' found in params","name":"UnexpectedParameter","stack":"UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ConsistentRead' found in params

As I can see there is no ConsistentRead param in dynamodb-2012-08-10.min.json

```
"Scan": {
  "input": {
    "type": "structure",
    "required": [
      "TableName"
    ],
    "members": {
      "TableName": {},
      "AttributesToGet": {
        "shape": "Sj"
      },
      "Limit": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "Select": {},
      "ScanFilter": {
        "shape": "S30"
      },
      "ConditionalOperator": {},
      "ExclusiveStartKey": {
        "shape": "S6"
      },
      "ReturnConsumedCapacity": {},
      "TotalSegments": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "Segment": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "ProjectionExpression": {},
      "FilterExpression": {},
      "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "shape": "Sm"
      },
      "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        "shape": "S2g"
      }
   }
},
```

I just found that in Release: AWS SDK for JavaScript v2.1.39
AWS.DynamoDB API Update

Submitted By:   Aditya@AWS
Created On:     July 14, 2015 7:36 PM GMT
Last Updated:   July 14, 2015 7:36 PM GMT

Updated AWS.DynamoDB API to add support for the ConsistentRead parameter with the Scan API operation.

So I need to update aws-sdk

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a library mismatch? Are you pulling the official AWS SDK? I see `ConsistentRead` in the [dynamodb-2012-08-10.min.json source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/apis/dynamodb-2012-08-10.min.json#L449-L451), so I would assume you are using a different API schema version than you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

This exceptions seems to occur for me as well with the python boto3 package. Although [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) indicates that the boolean parameter "ConsistentRead" may be added to the scan() method, when I add this parameter to my request using the client, I receive the following exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ConsistentRead", must be one of: TableName, IndexName, 
AttributesToGet, Limit, Select, ScanFilter, ConditionalOperator, ExclusiveStartKey, 
ReturnConsumedCapacity, TotalSegments, Segment, ProjectionExpression, FilterExpression, 
ExpressionAttributeNames, ExpressionAttributeValues
```

Since [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ReadConsistency.Scan) indicates that you can include a ConsistentRead parameter, I'm not sure whether this is a problem for me, the dynamodb local build that I have been using for testing, boto3 or the AWS api itself. Has anyone else gotten this parameter to work?

Comment: No but I now have the same problem with ProjectionExpression..!